# Display the month names available in quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to display the month names available in the Quarters.
Means like we have four quarters 1,2,3,4 in a year. I have following query.

```
select  datename(month,(DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) )
```

Output is :October

But How should I modify this query so that I should get the output as:

> ```
> October
> November
> December
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @quarter datetime
set @quarter = DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

select datename(month, @quarter)
union all
select datename(month, (DATEADD(month, 1, @quarter) ) )
union all
select datename(month, (DATEADD(month, 2, @quarter) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @d datetime = Dateadd(mm,0,getdate())
-- set @d = Dateadd(mm,-3,getdate())

;With Dates
AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,@d),0) AS StartDt,DATEPART(qq,@d) AS Qr
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(mm,1,StartDt),DATEPART(qq,DATEADD(mm,1,StartDt+1)-1)
FROM Dates
WHERE DATEPART(qq,DATEADD(mm,1,StartDt+1)-1)  = DATEPART(qq,@d)
)
SELECT 
datename(month,StartDt) Mnth, Qr,StartDt
FROM Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(m,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,getdate()), 0)) AS MonthsInQuarter
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(m,DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,getdate()),0))) 
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(m,DATEADD(mm,2,DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,getdate()),0)))
```